# Finding accuracy of water indices

Tags: accuracy, normalized-difference-water-index

I have calculated the water indices NDWI, MNDWI, WRI, and applied binary thresholding. I want to find out the accuracy of these indices.

Comment: A good definition of accuracy is "the degree to which the result of a measurement, calculation, or specification conforms to the correct value or a standard." So you need to specify some places where you can specify some correct values obtained from reliable sources and compare against them. There are many several different to do this once you know what you are comparing your indices against.

Comment: A confusion matrix? [Here](https://classeval.wordpress.com/introduction/basic-evaluation-measures/) is a blog discussing such technique.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous articles that explore the accuracy of NDWI, but as far as I know they really need a specific area of interest and ground truth measurements. See for example

Jovanovic, N., Garcia, C., Bugan, R., Teich, I., & Rodriguez, C. (2014). Validation of remotely-sensed evapotranspiration and NDWI using ground measurements at Riverlands, South Africa. In Water SA (Vol. 40, Issue 2, p. 211). Academy of Science of South Africa. https://doi.org/10.4314/wsa.v40i2.3

, where they find

> Multiple regression models showed that NDWI relates well to soil water content after accounting for precipitation (adjusted R2 were 0.71, 0.59 and 0.54 for 10, 40 and 80 cm soil depth, respectively).

.

I would advise you to seek ground truth measurements for your area of interest.